# ngModel with $index in ngRepeat

Tags: angularjs

Sample problem

```
<div ng-app="" ng-init="names=['Jani']">   
<ul>    
<li ng-repeat="x in names " >
<div ng:model="a[$index]" > 
<div ng:init="a{{$index}}='1'">
{{a0}}
</div>   
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

In above code, I can create dynamic ngModel variable. but I want to initiate value 1 to ngModel dynamically. Please help me

Comment: try this <div ng-init="a[$index]='1'">

Comment: In your first div tag, you have to initialize the array `<div ng-app="" ng-init="names=['Jani']"   a=[];>` . Then define the default value `<div ng:init="a[$index]='1'">`